# Is maven release:branch supposed to update scm url of the branch?

Tags: maven, svn, branch, release

I have this in my pom:

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:javasvn:http://url.com/repo/myProject/trunk</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:javasvn:http://url.com/repo/myProject/trunk</developerConnection>
    <url>http://url.com/websvn/listing.php?repname=repo&amp;path=/myProject/trunk</url>
</scm>
```

When I run:

```
mvn release:branch -DbranchName=myBranch
```

It creates successfully the branch here :

```
http://url.com/repo/myProject/branches/myBranch
```

But when I look into the pom.xml of this branch, the "scm" part remains the same as the trunk

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:javasvn:http://url.com/repo/myProject/trunk</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:javasvn:http://url.com/repo/myProject/trunk</developerConnection>
    <url>http://url.com/websvn/listing.php?repname=repo&amp;path=/myProject/trunk</url>
</scm>
```

[Doc says](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/branch.html):

- > Transform the SCM information in the POM to include the final
  >   destination of the tag

Isn't the plugin supposed to replace "/trunk" by "/branches/myBranch"? Or are we supposed to do this manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced

```
scm:javasvn:http://...
```

with

```
scm:svn:http://...
```

And the transformation is done now.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin replaces "trunk" by the "branches/myBranch" but don't switch your working copy. In the new created branch, viewing the remote pom.xml the scm info should have changed for that branch. maven:release fails if it cannot commit the changes.

```
r1643
[maven-release-plugin] prepare for next development iteration
---------------------
r1642
[maven-release-plugin]  copy for branch a-project-1.0
---------------------
r1641
[maven-release-plugin] prepare branch a-project-1.0
---------------------
```

Is your svn log looking like this at the revision you created the branch?

In this example, **r1641** changed the pom scm info from "trunk" to "branches/a-project-1.0".
**r1642** copied the trunk to the branch, creating it.
**r1643** changed the pom scm info from "branches/a-project-1.0" to "trunk" again so you remain at trunk in your working copy.

When I've used maven release and it failed, always has shown an error at the command line and left temporal files at my working copy that have to be deleted or cleaned with **mvn --batch-mode release:clean**.

Try changing your scm.url to "http://url.com/repo/myProject/trunk" instead of "http://url.com/websvn/listing.php?repname=repo&path=/myProject/trunk" (I don't think maven can change your current url parameter)
Then go again with: **mvn --batch-mode -DbranchName="A_TEST" -Darguments="-DskipTests=true"**
and check console errors, the svn log at the svn projects root folder, and also check for local working copy modifications.
If all should have been OK and it's not, check your maven runtime version. I've got some problems working with maven:release and maven 3.0.5 when releasing tags. I only use maven 3.1+ for branching/releasing automation purposes.

Comment: Why am I still having "trunk" then?

Comment: I've added more info. Hope will help your problem.

Comment: Tried all (batch mode, changing the url format) without any success. I'm still having "trunk" in the scm part of the branch. No error in logs. Created an issue here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-922